# insert line on first instance of of a value

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, ifs

i am trying to insert a row on the first instance where the value in column y is above 60. Only one row.

i did a loop to insert multiple rows for anything above 60 but i dont need this.

having difficulty changing this

here's what i got

```
     Dim Col As Variant
    Dim BlankRows As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim StartRow As Long

    

        Col = "Y"
        StartRow = 1
        BlankRows = 1

            LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False

            With ActiveSheet
 For i = LastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1
 If .Cells(i, Col) > 60 Then
 .Cells(i, Col).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

    
 End If
 Next i
 End With
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: `first instance` - do you mean as you scan down the sheet or up ? Is the new row  to be inserted below or above the row that is > 60.

Comment: Reading code is a lot easier if you keep the indentation properly aligned (so that, for example, `For` and the corresponding `Next` have the same indent and the lines within the loop are further indented).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Do loop for this (2 search direction variants):

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertRowSearchDown()
    Dim out As Boolean, cl As Range
    
    Set cl = ActiveSheet.Range("Y1")    'start cell
    Do Until out                        'initially out=False
        If cl > 60 Then
            cl.EntireRow.Insert
            out = True
        Else
            Set cl = cl.Offset(1)       'move DOWN to the next row
            out = IsEmpty(cl)
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub InsertRowSearchUp()
    Dim out As Boolean, cl As Range
    
    Set cl = ActiveSheet.Range("Y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)        'start cell
    Do Until out                            'initially out=False
        If cl > 60 Then
            cl.EntireRow.Insert
            out = True
        Else
            If cl.Row = 1 Then
                out = True
            Else
                Set cl = cl.Offset(-1)          'move UP to the previous row
            End If
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `GoTo` to skip the following iterations once a `true` is done.

```
Dim Col As Variant
Dim BlankRows As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim StartRow As Long

        Col = "Y"
        StartRow = 1
        BlankRows = 1

            LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ActiveSheet
 For i = LastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1
 If .Cells(i, Col) > 60 Then
 .Cells(i, Col).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
Goto: Close
 End If
 Next i
 End With

Close
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub
```

Comment: or just an Exit For in your if clause will do the trick.

Comment: Hi @ceci I think the problem with using the `Exit` is it will close the subroutine before it gets a chance to turn screen updating back on, whereas the `GoTo:` allows the OP to still execute the part that does this. Otherwise this would be a good alternative and much simpler to include.

Comment: nope the "exit for" will just exit the for loop and then continue with the rest of the code.

Comment: pardon me, @ceci I missed the `For` part of the `Exit For`. This would also work, thanks for alternative, apologies for the oversight on my part.